# Can't pass string to MySQL stored procedure using adodb

Tags: php, mysql, adodb

I'm using adodb5 to call this stored procedure but **MySQL doesn't understand $sealID is a string**.

```
$db = NewADOConnection('mysql://'.DB_USER.':'.DB_PASS.'@'.DB_SERVER.'/'.DB_NAME);
$sql = "CALL GetSeal($userID, $sealID, @result)";
$r = $db->Execute($sql);
```

When I run this php from shell.

```
TestGetSealProc.php 3155011 ZZZZNLJSAYGZECWY
```

MySQL reports:

```
Unknown column 'ZZZZNLJSAYGZECWY' in 'field list'
```

ZZZZNLJSAYGZECWY must be understood as a string but a column. How to fix it?

**Update:** first part of my stored proc.

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetSeal`(IN userID INT, IN sealID char(16), OUT result INT)
    BEGIN

        DECLARE imageCnt INT;
        DECLARE pointCnt INT;
        DECLARE puriCode varchar(256);
        DECLARE newImgID INT;
....

        DECLARE c_data CURSOR FOR
            SELECT TELEPHONE_NUMBER, IMG_FILENAME, SELECTION_FLG, PHOTOGRAPH_DATE, SEND_DATE
            FROM re_photograph_imgs
            WHERE SEAL_NUMBER = sealID
            AND IMG_FILENAME IS NOT NULL
            AND IMG_FILENAME != "";
```

......................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget quotes. Without them, a bare string will be interpreted as a field name:

```
$sql = "CALL GetSeal($userID, '$sealID', @result)";
                              ^       ^
```